# Альтернатива двойной диспетчеризации

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, проектирование, производительность

Необходимо решить несколько задач оптимизации в agario подобной игре - большая комната, с несколькими тысячами объектов разных типов, разные типы взаимодействуют между собой, но не все со всеми.

1. Снизить затраты на просчет взаимодействия игровых объектов.
2. Уменьшить сетевой трафик и затраты на отслеживание изменений.

В качестве решения я выбрал замену монолитной комнаты на карту секторов (вектор секторов, соответсвующий двумерной карте). Взаимодействие отслеживается только между объектами внутри сектора. Напрашивается следующая структура сектора:

```
struct Sector {
  std::set<Cell*> cells;
  uint16_t id {0};
};
```

Само взаимодействие просто реализовать посредством двойной диспетчеризации. Смущает что в данном случае необходимо постоянно отслеживать взаимодействие всех со всеми (но уже внутри сектора). Понятно что это намного эффективнее, нежели то же самое в одном большом секторе (целой комнате). Но, например сейчас, у меня взаимодействие расчитывается (хоть и в целой комнате) только между теми объектами между которыми в принципе может быть взаимодействие.

ЗЫ. Или не заморачиваться и пилить двойную диспетчеризацию, а то пока писал сообщение понял что в моей игре пока еще не взаимодействуют только 4 типа объектов и то только одного и того же типа.

Comment: классический совет в подобных случаях - профилировали?

Comment: @KoVadim, конечно да. Хотя уже сомневаюсь о чем Ваш коментарий. Я профилировал именно текущий вариант - комната как один большой сектор и без двойной диспетчеризации, и он меня не устроил. Разбивку на сектора + двойная диспетчеризация не профилировал так как еще не начал пилить этот вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проанализировав варианты взаимодействия объектов, я нашел ответ  в несколько иной плоскости. Согласно геймдизайна - неподвижные тела не взаимодействуют друг с другом. Поэтому хорошим решением в совокупности с двойной диспетчеризацией будет исключение из перебора *невозможных* вариантов взаимодействия.

Мое решение - заводим два контейнера:

1. Gridmap - неподвижные тела, разбитые по квадратным секторам (до 10K объектов).
2. `std::set<Cell*>` - движущиеся тела (таких объектов очень мало, менее 100).

На каждой итерации обрабатываются взаимодействия между каждым движущимся телом и телами из секторов в которых находится это тело, а также попарно между собой все движущиеся тела. Остановившиеся тела или, наоборот, начавшие движение перемещаются в соответсвующий контейнер.

Answer (score 1):

Для разбиения карты на сектора есть общепринятое название — spatial hashing. Помимо деления на сектора, в таком подходе применяются дополнительные улучшения:

- взаимодействие расчитывается не для объектов в одном и том же секторе, а для объектов, находящихся в одном и том же или в соседних секторах. При этом подразумевается, что размер сектора превышает максимальное расстояние для взаимодействия.
- если плотность занятых ячеек небольшая, то для ускорения обновления можно применить хеширование координат объекта по приципу `x + y * height` с округлением, и хранить объекты в хеш-массиве вместо двумерной матрицы.

Comment: Так и делаю. Замечу, что перечислены не все возможные улучшения, и для разных задач уместны разные улучшения. Например в моем случае размер хотябы одного тела может многократно превышать размер сектора, поэтому обычная практика проверять центральный сектор и 8 соседних тут неприменима. Подход с хешированием я применяю для самих секторов - `std::vector<Sector>`, так как это неизменяемые данные. Для движущихся тел, скорее всего, нету выгоды от хеширования координат, так как они слишком часто меняются (или я не понял как это использовать). Оптимальнее будет сортировать по более заполненной оси.